# Rails: Can I send a GET request to a create path?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, get

I'm trying to append new comments to a list of existing comments using javascript and ajax. I set up my Comments#create to create a new comment and then render its text. But how can I access this text with ajax?

**controllers/comments_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @comment = Comment.new
  @comments = Comment.all
end

def create
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:thing_id])
  @comment = @thing.comments.create(comment_params)
  render text: @comment.text.to_s + "".html_safe
end
```

**My form for a new comment and ajax/javascript attempt:**

```
  <%= form_for([@thing, @comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :text, :placeholder => "Explain your rating..." %>
    <div id="btn"><%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn", id: "postacomment" %></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#postacomment").click(function() {
        $.get( "<%= new_thing_comment_path(:id => @comment.id) %>", function( data ) {
          $('#comments_h2').prepend( data );
        });
      });
    </script>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't try to bend HTTP methods to fill your needs, follow them instead.

If you want to respond to javascript with rails, that is fairly easy. On your comments controller:

```
  def new
   @comment = Comment.new
   @comments = Comment.all
  end

  def create
   @thing = Thing.find(params[:thing_id])
   @comment = @thing.comments.create(comment_params)
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to new_comments_path } #this is just a redirection in case JS is disabled 
    format.js
   end
  end
```

As you can see we are now responding to two types of formats, in this case `html` and `js`, this forces you to have those corresponding views, or at least for the `js` version which may look like this:

**app/views/comments/create.js.erb:**

```
$('#comments_h2').prepend("<%= j @comment %>");
```

In the example above I'm assuming you have a partial for rendering a comment, it should look something like:

**app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb:**

```
<h2><%= comment.content %></h2>
```

Obviously you have to update that file to meet your needs.

Hope it helps!